# How to enable a Spark-Mesos job to be launched from inside a Docker container?

Tags: apache-spark, docker, pyspark, mesos

## Summary:

Is it possible to submit a Spark job on Mesos from inside a Docker container with 1 Mesos master (no Zookeeper) and 1 Mesos agent also each running in separate Docker containers (on the same host for now)?  The Mesos containerizer described at http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/container-image/ seems to apply to the case where the Mesos application is simply encapsulated in a Docker container and run.  My Docker application is more interactive with multiple PySpark Mesos jobs being instantiated at run-time based on user input.  The driver program in the Docker container is not itself run as a Mesos app.  Only the user-initiated job requests are handled as PySpark Mesos apps.

## Specifics:

I have 3 Docker containers based on centos:7 linux, and running on the same host machine for now:

1. Container "Master" running a Mesos Master.
2. Container "Agent" running a Mesos Agent.
3. Container "Test"  with Spark and Mesos installed where I run a bash shell and launch the following PySpark test program from the command line.

   ```
   from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
   from operator import add

   # Configure Spark                                               
   sp_conf = SparkConf()
   sp_conf.setAppName("spark_test")
   sp_conf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
   sp_conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false")
   sp_conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "500m")
   sp_conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "500m")
   sp_conf.set("spark.executor.cores", 1)
   sp_conf.set("spark.cores.max", 1)
   sp_conf.set("spark.mesos.executor.home", "/usr/local/spark-2.1.0")
   sp_conf.set("spark.executor.uri", "file://usr/local/spark-2.1.0-bin-without-hadoop.tgz")
   sc = SparkContext(conf=sp_conf)

   # Simple computation
   x = [(1.5,100.),(1.5,200.),(1.5,300.),(2.5,150.)]
   rdd = sc.parallelize(x,1)
   tot = rdd.foldByKey(0,add).collect()
   cnt = rdd.countByKey()
   time = [t[0] for t in tot]
   avg = [t[1]/cnt[t[0]] for t in tot]
   print 'tot=', tot
   print 'cnt=', cnt
   print 't=', time
   print 'avg=', avg
   ```

The relevant software versions I am using are as follows:

- Hadoop: 2.7.3
- Spark: 2.1.0
- Mesos: 1.2.0
- Docker: 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e

### The following works fine:

- I can run the simple PySpark test program above from inside the Test container with Spark's `MASTER=local[N]` for `N=1` or `N=4`.
- I can see in the Mesos logs and in the Mesos user interface (UI) that the Mesos agent and master come up fine.  The Mesos UI shows that the agent is connected with plenty of resources (cpu, memory, disk).
- I can run the Mesos Python tests successfully from inside the Test container with `/usr/local/mesos-1.2.0/build/src/examples/python/test-framework 127.0.0.1:5050`.  This seems to confirm that the Mesos containers can be accessed from within my Test container, but these tests are not using Spark.

### This is the Failure:

With Spark's `MASTER=mesos://127.0.0.1:5050`, when I launch my PySpark test program from inside the Test container there is activity in the logs of both the Mesos Master and Agent, and in the couple seconds before failure, the Mesos UI shows resources assigned for the job that are well within what is available.  However, the PySpark test program then fails with:  *WARN scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources*.

The steps I followed are as follows.

### Start Mesos Master:

```
docker run -it --net=host -p 5050:5050 the_master
```

Relevant excerpts from the master's log shows:

> I0418 01:05:08.540192    27 master.cpp:383] Master 15b354eb-6a20-4bc9-a13b-6533b1e91bd2 (localhost) started on 127.0.0.1:5050
>   I0418 01:05:08.540210    27 master.cpp:385] Flags at startup: --agent_ping_timeout="15secs" --agent_reregister_timeout="10mins" --allocation_interval="1secs" --allocator="HierarchicalDRF" --authenticate_agents="false" --authenticate_frameworks="false" --authenticate_http_frameworks="false" --authenticate_http_readonly="false" --authenticate_http_readwrite="false" --authenticators="crammd5" --authorizers="local" --framework_sorter="drf" --help="false" --hostname_lookup="true" --http_authenticators="basic" --initialize_driver_logging="true" --log_auto_initialize="true" --logbufsecs="0" --logging_level="INFO" --max_agent_ping_timeouts="5" --max_completed_frameworks="50" --max_completed_tasks_per_framework="1000" --max_unreachable_tasks_per_framework="1000" --quiet="false" --recovery_agent_removal_limit="100%" --registry="replicated_log" --registry_fetch_timeout="1mins" --registry_gc_interval="15mins" --registry_max_agent_age="2weeks" --registry_max_agent_count="102400" --registry_store_timeout="20secs" --registry_strict="false" --root_submissions="true" --user_sorter="drf" --version="false" --webui_dir="/usr/local/mesos-1.2.0/build/../src/webui" --work_dir="/var/lib/mesos" --zk_session_timeout="10secs"

### Start Mesos Agent:

```
docker run -it --net=host -e MESOS_AGENT_PORT=5051 the_agent
```

The agent's log shows:

> I0418 01:42:00.234244    40 slave.cpp:212] Flags at startup: --appc_simple_discovery_uri_prefix="http://" --appc_store_dir="/tmp/mesos/store/appc" --authenticate_http_readonly="false" --authenticate_http_readwrite="false" --authenticatee="crammd5" --authentication_backoff_factor="1secs" --authorizer="local" --cgroups_cpu_enable_pids_and_tids_count="false" --cgroups_enable_cfs="false" --cgroups_hierarchy="/sys/fs/cgroup" --cgroups_limit_swap="false" --cgroups_root="mesos" --container_disk_watch_interval="15secs" --containerizers="mesos" --default_role="*" --disk_watch_interval="1mins" --docker="docker" --docker_kill_orphans="true" --docker_mesos_image="spark-mesos-agent-test" --docker_registry="https://registry-1.docker.io" --docker_remove_delay="6hrs" --docker_socket="/var/run/docker.sock" --docker_stop_timeout="0ns" --docker_store_dir="/tmp/mesos/store/docker" --docker_volume_checkpoint_dir="/var/run/mesos/isolators/docker/volume" --enforce_container_disk_quota="false" --executor_registration_timeout="1mins" --executor_shutdown_grace_period="5secs" --fetcher_cache_dir="/tmp/mesos/fetch" --fetcher_cache_size="2GB" --frameworks_home="" --gc_delay="1weeks" --gc_disk_headroom="0.1" --hadoop_home="" --help="false" --hostname_lookup="true" --http_authenticators="basic" --http_command_executor="false" --http_heartbeat_interval="30secs" --initialize_driver_logging="true" --isolation="posix/cpu,posix/mem" --launcher="posix" --launcher_dir="/usr/local/mesos-1.2.0/build/src" --logbufsecs="0" --logging_level="INFO" --max_completed_executors_per_framework="150" --oversubscribed_resources_interval="15secs" --perf_duration="10secs" --perf_interval="1mins" --qos_correction_interval_min="0ns" --quiet="false" --recover="reconnect" --recovery_timeout="15mins" --registration_backoff_factor="1secs" --revocable_cpu_low_priority="true" --runtime_dir="/var/run/mesos" --sandbox_directory="/mnt/mesos/sandbox" --strict="true" --switch_user="false" --systemd_enable_support="false" --systemd_runtime_directory="/run/systemd/system" --version="false" --work_dir="/var/lib/mesos"

I get the following warning for both the Mesos Master and Agent, but ignore it because I am running everything on the same host for now:

> Master/Agent bound to loopback interface! Cannot communicate with remote schedulers or agents. You might want to set '--ip' flag to a routable IP address.

In fact, my tests with assigning a routable IP address instead of 127.0.0.1 failed to change any of the behavior I describe here.

### Start Test Container (with bash shell for testing):

```
docker run -it --net=host the_test /bin/bash
```

Some relevant environment variables set inside all three container (Master, Agent, and Test):

> HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3
>   HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/etc/hadoop
>   SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark-2.1.0
>   SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI=file:////usr/local/spark-2.1.0-bin-without-hadoop.tgz
>   MASTER=mesos://127.0.0.1:5050
>   PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/anaconda2/bin/python
>   PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/local/anaconda2/bin/python
>   PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS=--driver-memory=4g pyspark-shell
>   MESOS_PORT=5050
>   MESOS_IP=127.0.0.1
>   MESOS_WORKDIR=/var/lib/mesos
>   MESOS_HOME=/usr/local/mesos-1.2.0
>   MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libmesos.so
>   MESOS_MASTER=mesos://127.0.0.1:5050
>   PYTHONPATH=:/usr/local/spark-2.1.0/python:/usr/local/spark-2.1.0/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip

Run Mesos (non-Spark) tests from inside the Test container:

```
/usr/local/mesos-1.2.0/build/src/examples/python/test-framework 127.0.0.1:5050
```

This produces the following log output (as expected I think):

> I0417 21:28:36.912542    20 sched.cpp:232] Version: 1.2.0
>   I0417 21:28:36.920013    62 sched.cpp:336] New master detected at master@127.0.0.1:5050
>   I0417 21:28:36.920472    62 sched.cpp:352] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication
>   I0417 21:28:36.924165    62 sched.cpp:759] Framework registered with be89e739-be8d-430e-b1e9-3fe55fa18459-0000
>   Registered with framework ID be89e739-be8d-430e-b1e9-3fe55fa18459-0000
>   Received offer be89e739-be8d-430e-b1e9-3fe55fa18459-O0 with cpus: 16.0 and mem: 119640.0
>   Launching task 0 using offer be89e739-be8d-430e-b1e9-3fe55fa18459-O0
>   Launching task 1 using offer be89e739-be8d-430e-b1e9-3fe55fa18459-O0
>   Launching task 2 using offer be89e739-be8d-430e-b1e9-3fe55fa18459-O0
>   Launching task 3 using offer be89e739-be8d-430e-b1e9-3fe55fa18459-O0
>   Launching task 4 using offer be89e739-be8d-430e-b1e9-3fe55fa18459-O0
>   Task 0 is in state TASK_RUNNING
>   Task 1 is in state TASK_RUNNING
>   Task 2 is in state TASK_RUNNING
>   Task 3 is in state TASK_RUNNING
>   Task 4 is in state TASK_RUNNING
>   Task 0 is in state TASK_FINISHED
>   Task 1 is in state TASK_FINISHED
>   Task 2 is in state TASK_FINISHED
>   Task 3 is in state TASK_FINISHED
>   Task 4 is in state TASK_FINISHED
>   All tasks done, waiting for final framework message
>   Received message: 'data with a \x00 byte'
>   Received message: 'data with a \x00 byte'
>   Received message: 'data with a \x00 byte'
>   Received message: 'data with a \x00 byte'
>   Received message: 'data with a \x00 byte'
>   All tasks done, and all messages received, exiting

Run PySpark test program from inside the Test container:

```
python spark_test.py
```

This produces the following log output:

> 17/04/17 21:29:18 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>   I0417 21:29:19.187747   205 sched.cpp:232] Version: 1.2.0
>   I0417 21:29:19.196535   188 sched.cpp:336] New master detected at master@127.0.0.1:5050
>   I0417 21:29:19.197453   188 sched.cpp:352] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication
>   I0417 21:29:19.201884   195 sched.cpp:759] Framework registered with be89e739-be8d-430e-b1e9-3fe55fa18459-0001
>   17/04/17 21:29:34 WARN scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

I searched for this error on the internet but every page I found indicates that it is a common error caused by insufficient resources being allocated to the Mesos agent.  As I mentioned, the Mesos UI indicates that there are sufficient resources.  Please respond if you have any idea why my Spark job is not accepting resources from Mesos or if you have any suggestions of things I could try.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is now resolved.  In case anybody encounters a similar problem, I wanted to post that in my case it was caused by the HADOOP CLASSPATH not being set in the Mesos Master and Agent containers.  Once set, everything works as expected.